# Angular - Is it possible to perform a switch statement rather than multiple @Input()s?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am passing an attribute into my Angular component in the form of:

```
<my-component myAttribute></my-component>
```

In order to change a variable within the component that determines the CSS for `width` & `height`.

I also have pre-defined attribute values established such that inputting:

```
<my-component large>
```

Will set the `width` and `height` variables to equal `100` (100px after processing).

However, I am curious as to whether I can write multiple `@Input()` criteria in a way that I will not have lots of separate `@Input()`s, perhaps using a switch statement that will do the same job?

I have attempted this a little, but only received a sea of red squigglies under the code.

**my inputs**

```
size = 50 // Default value

  @Input('small') set small(value) {
    this.size = !value ? 25 : this.size;
  }

  @Input('medium') set medium(value) {
    this.size = !value ? 50 : this.size;
  }

  @Input('large') set large(value) {
    this.size = !value ? 100 : this.size;
  }

  @Input('x-large') set xlarge(value) {
    this.size = !value ? 200 : this.size;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a way, but it is ... unconventional. I'm only able to perform it, I can't tell you if you should use it or not. So try it at your own risk.

This method ([that you can find working here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/size-directive-for-div-86y39i?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)) gets rid of inputs and use the root Element of your component :

```
export class HelloComponent {
  size = '120';

  attributes = {
    'x-small': 50,
    'small': 75,
    'medium': 100,
    'large': 125,
    'x-large': 150,
  };

  constructor(
    private el: ElementRef<HTMLElement>
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.setSize();
  }

  private setSize() {
    const attr = Object.keys(this.attributes).forEach(attr => {
      const hasAttribute = this.el.nativeElement.hasAttribute(attr);
      this.size = hasAttribute && this.attributes[attr] || this.size;
    });
  }

  getSize() {
    const myStyle = {
      width: this.size + 'px',
      height: this.size + 'px'
    };
    return myStyle;
  }

}
```

What it does is basically trying to find an attribute listed in the attributes object, and if it finds it, it sets the value corresponding to that attribute.

**EDIT** When you create private functions, they are accessible only on the component itself (kind of). This means they can't produce side effects on other components and *don't really* have to be tested.

For instance you could test a size like this

```
it('should be 100px wide when setSize', () => {
  component['el'].nativeElement.setAttribute('medium', '');
  component.setSize();
  expect(component.size).toEqual(100);
});
```

It is called an **implementation detail** : it's kind of like I've been telling you before : your `setSize` function is now abstracted, you assume it works and you test that when you call it, your size is effectively changing.

This means you don't have to test the inside of the `setSize` function, only that it behaves accordingly !

But you have to test **all possibilities** to prevent side effects : for instance, what happens if the attribute isn't `medium`, but `exxxtra-large` ? This is a case that you need to test.

This should fasten up your tests !

Comment: I just had a quick play with the StackBlitz subbing in my real-world variable names. Is the line `const elAttributes = this.el.nativeElement.attributes;` really necessary? It isn't used after being assigned

Comment: Actually, having a further investigation, you can get rid of the `const elAttributes` and the `i` found in `forEach((attr, i)`

Comment: @physicsboy Sorry, my own IDE warns me of unused variables, but not stackblitz !

Comment: At least it works ;-) Now I just have the fun of changing my tests XD

Comment: You can render this as an implementation detail, would you like an example ?

Comment: That would be amazing :D

Comment: Big downvote for bringing Justin Bieber into this! :P I understand about not wanting to test things because they just do a small thing that will not affect anything else. But my team absolutely love coverage reports! So thank you for showing me how I would test :-)

Comment: It will be covered because you call the function. Code coverage isn't made with expects, but with what instructions Javascript has ran. If you never call `setSize`, you won't have any coverage, but here, since we call it, you'll have it covered. ANd if you call it 5 times, you'll have it covered 5 times (Istanbul puts factors at the start of lines, check it out)

Answer (score 0):

Pass the input as an object instead of a number. Then you can intercept the value passed using either:

a setter (as per your current attempt) OR

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#intercept-input-property-changes-with-a-setter

ngOnChanges

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#intercept-input-property-changes-with-ngonchanges

Using a setter, assuming dimensions is an object passed in, you might do this:

```
private _width = 0;
private _height = 0;

@Input()
set dimensions(dimensions: any) {
  this._width = dimensions.width
  this._height = dimensions.height
  // could put a switch case here
}

get width(): string { return this._width; }
get height(): string { return this._height; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could control and calculate the size of the child component within the parent component and send an object with variable properties. Once you have calculated this you could receive this value via 1 single input, say `size`.

*Parent Component*

```
<my-component size="this.childSize"></my-component>
```

*Child Component*

```
 private _size: any;

 @Input('size') set size(value) {
   this._size = value;

   const property = Object.keys(this.size)[0]; // expecting only 1 property

     switch (property):
       case 'small':
         // do something
         console.log(this.size[property]);
         break;
       case 'large':
         // do something
         break;
       default:
        // do something
   }

 public get size(): any {
   return this._size;
 }
```

Of course, you should create your own type for `childSize` to indicate & restrict what properties could be there. Examples, of objects you could send..

```
{
 small: 15
}

{
 large: 35
}
```